Redirect to /dashboard_sample.php on login
Using Drupal V10, with Rules V4, I Want user 'client1' to be redirected on login straight to '/dashboard_sample.php'.
I have client1 set up with role 'jh_dashboard'.
The rule I set up is:

Event user has logged in rules_user_login
Condition 'Parameters: user: account, roles: [jh_dashboard], operation: AND
Page Redirect 'Parameters: url: /dashboard_sample.php'

On login, I keep getting

The website encountered an unexpected error. Try again later.*

If I hit reload, I get to my account page, with the Rules Evaluation Log, showing The requested page could not be found.
/dashboard_sample.php definitely exists and can be accessed otherwise.
Have I got the condition set up wrong?
I have been using Rules in Drupal 7 for years with no problem.

And putting an absolute URL?

"The website encountered an unexpected error." What is in the logs about that error?

Better use ECA instead of Rules.

Approach it systematically. First remove the Condition to see if your redirect works properly. If that works then the problem was the Condition. Check your server logs and Drupal logs to see exactly what the error said. Does that role exist?
The rules_examples module has many examples you can import and inspect, including one that shows you how to redirect on login.
